# Trying to use the dynamodb immutable class with a composite key (Java, SpringBoot) and not sure how to initialize the PK

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to create a composite key with dynamodb and a java spring boot application.  Currently running into some issues, believe it's related to a missing setter?  I know that lombok interferes with the dynamodb annotations.  Here is my code:

```
@DynamoDbImmutable(builder = UserEntity.Builder.class)
public class UserEntity {
    private final UUID accountId;
    private final UUID userId;
    private final Instant createDate;

    private UserEntity(Builder b) {
        this.accountId = UUID.fromString(b.accountId);
        this.createDate = b.createDate;
    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    @DynamoDbPartitionKey
    @DynamoDbAttribute("pk")
    @DynamoDbIgnore
    public String getPartitionKey(){
        return "ACCOUNT#" + accountId;
    }

    @DynamoDbSortKey
    @DynamoDbAttribute("sk")
    @DynamoDbIgnore
    public String getSortKey() {
        return  "USER#" + userId;
    }

   public static final class Builder {
        private String accountId;
        private String userId;

        public Builder () {}

        @DynamoDbIgnore
        public Builder pk() {
            //Do nothing
            return this;
        }

        @DynamoDbIgnore
        public Builder sk() {
            //Do nothing
            return this;
        }
        @DynamoDbIgnore
        public Builder accountId(String accountId){ this.accountId = accountId; return this; }
        @DynamoDbIgnore
        public Builder userId(String userId){ this.userId = userId; return this; }
        @DynamoDbIgnore
        public Builder createDate(Instant createDate){ this.createDate = createDate; return this; }

        public UserEntity build() {
            return new UserEntity(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get when I run the code is:

```
    Attempt to execute an operation that requires a primary index without defining any primary key     attributes in the table metadata.
```

I believe it's a lombok getter reference interfering with the immutable class, but not sure what I'm missing (ref: https://davidagood.com/dynamodb-enhanced-client-java-missing-setters/)
The table does seem to exist when I'm running localstack with dynamodb.

I've already tried reverting back to the @DynamoDBBean annotation several times, as well as tried using the getter annotation that I've search all over the internet for, but none of the examples show me how I can create a composite primary key.